# What are the coordinates of your position?

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

Suppose you start at the origin, move along the x-axis 3 units.
Then face downwards and move forward 4 units. Then turn right and move
7 units. Then (relative to your current position) face downwards and move
forward 3 units. What are the coordinates of your position?

What I did using the description given:

step 1- move along the x-axis 3 units: $x=3$

2-Then face downwards and move forward 4 units: $x=3, z=-4$

3-Then turn right and move
7 units: $x=3, z=-4, y= 7$

4-face downwards and move
forward 3 units: $x=3, z=-1, y= 7$

The point is (3,7,-1)

But the answer is wrong, how could I know the points from the description?

Comment: Don't you think that saying downward and right will depend upon the relative orientation of co-ordinate axes

Comment: If lets say going upward and downward means z, right and left is y, then x is what?

Comment: That's given in the question?

Comment: @Alpha no, just assuming

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret this, you should also keep track of which direction you're facing, and what is your sense of "down". This is what I got:

Step one: Move along the $x$-axis: $(3, 0, 0)$, your face points in the positive $x$-direction, your feet point in the negative $z$-direction.

Step two: Face downwards, and move forwards $4$ steps: $(3, 0, -4)$, face is now in the negative $z$-direction, and feet are in the negative $x$-direction.

Step three: Turn right and move seven units: $(3, -7, -4)$, face is in the negative $y$-direction, feet are in the negative $x$-direction.

Step four: Turn down (relative to your current orientation) and move forward $3$ units: $(0,-7, -4)$, face in the negative $x$-direction, feet in the positive $y$-direction.

Comment: The given solution is (0 -4, -7). does it matter? and thanks for explaining